# Enumerating positive fractions (reference missing)

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

I remember that the recursion

$r(0)=0, \ \
r(n+1)=\frac{1}{2 [r(n)]+1-r(n)}$ 
produces a sequence of rational values $ 0 \mapsto 1  \mapsto 1/2 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 1/3 \mapsto ... $ which exausts the positive fractions (and of course every fraction can only appear once).

Unfortunately I do not remember the reference for this statement. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at chapter 19 ("Sets, Functions and the continuum hypothesis") in "Proofs from THE BOOK" (5th edition) by Aigner/ Ziegler.

The sequence originates in the paper "Recounting the Rationals" by Calkin/Wilf but in this paper you can't find the formula you mention.

Comment: Thank you! Actually the keyword "Calkin/Wilf" is really useful: with this you can find also several references online (Wikipedia, OEIS, etc.).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree#Breadth_first_traversal

Comment: The answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/200656/is-there-a-natural-bijection-from-mathbbn-to-mathbbq also contain a lot information.